# Images don't show up in ListView Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i'm trying to create a listView with Images , but they don't show up when i run the emulator , any recommendations ?
I created a class Contact with two simple attributes : Name and Image .
MainPage.xaml :

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate >
     <ImageCell Text="{Binding Name}" ImageSource="{Biding Image}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs :

```
InitializeComponent();
listView.ItemsSource=new List<Contact>{
   new Contact{Name="Yassine" , Image="banana.jpg"},
   new Contact{Name="Ghita" , Image="strawberry.jpg"}
```

};

Here is the result :

[image]

Thank you !

Comment: Have you placed the pictures inside your Resources/drawable folder for android?

Comment: It might just be a copy paste or typing error, but in your `ImageSource` property, you misspelled **Binding**.

Comment: I think the same as @GeralexGR. And buy some license for Windows, if you don't want to pay the software that isn't free nobody will pay for your services either.

Comment: No i placed the pictures directly in the solution , that doesn't work ?

Comment: Sorry @IvanIčin , underdeveloped country , no money for it !

Comment: Move your images from the solution into the correct folder, which is Resources/drawable

Comment: @YassineElBaaj no you must place the images in the appropriate folders. For android under Resources/drawable , for UWP in the root folder of the project and for iOS under Resources

Comment: @YassineElBaaj that’s not the excuse, I live in a similar country and have the Windows license. Every developer with some basic capabilities can earn that much no matter where he lives. If he can’t it may be a sign to think about some other profession.